# Автозаполнение поля формы получая id вопроса django

Tags: python, django, django-model

Создаю свой форум. Пытаюсь сделать ответы на вопросы я сделал автозаполнение поле User_id в таблице Quetions и а таблице Answer user_id :

models.py

```
class Quetions(models.Model):
User_id = models.ForeignKey
(User,to_field='id',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,verbose_name='Пользователь',blank=True)
category_id = models.ForeignKey
(Category,to_field='id',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,verbose_name='Предмет')
schoolclass = models.ForeignKey
(SchoolClass,to_field='id',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,verbose_name='Класс')
subject =  models.CharField(max_length=255,verbose_name='Тема вопроса')
text = models.TextField(verbose_name='Вопрос')
img = models.ImageField(blank=True)
date_published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


def __str__(self):
   return f'Тема {self.subject}'

class Meta:
   verbose_name_plural = 'Вопрос'

class Answer(models.Model):
id_questions = 
models.ForeignKey(Quetions,to_field='id',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,verbose_name='К 
какому вопросу',blank=True)
user_id = models.ForeignKey.
(User,to_field='id',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,verbose_name='Пользователь', blank=True)
Text = models.TextField(verbose_name='Вопрос')
date_published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return f'Тема {self.id_questions}'

class Meta:
  verbose_name_plural = 'Ответ'
```

---

Автозаполнение в двух таблицах я сделал так:

views.py

```
def Questions(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    user = request.user
    form = QuestionsForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.User_id = user
        form.save()
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        return redirect('/')
else:
    form = QuestionsForm()
    model = Quetions.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'Questions.html', {'form': form,'model':model})
```

---

Не понимаю как сделать автозаполнение поле id_questions в таблице Answer при клике на вопрос? Заранее СПАСИБО

Answer (score 0):

```
if form.is_valid():
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    instance.User_id = user
    form.save()
```

Поле User_id это ForeignKey, значит нужно сохранить модель внешнего ключа:
instance.User_id.save()